# Kendo UI read not getting current data from grid

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a grid that contains a list of Id's with a button which contains state (Boolean Y/N) ,
I am calling a function at the click of a button to get all N Id's which is loading data from the grid.

```
function getAll(){

                        var page =  $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page();
                        console.log(page);
                        var onlyFailedIds = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read().then(function(){console.log(dataSource.view()[0].items.filter(row=>row.status==='N').map(row=>row.Id) )});
                        
               }
```

The problem is that I am always getting results of page 1 even when I change the page of grid.
How do I get results from other pages?

Answer (score 1):

You are using DataSource's view method. According to the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/view):

> Returns the data items which correspond to the current page, filter, sort, and group configuration.

You should be using the DataSource's data method. According to the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/data):

> Gets or sets the data items of the data source.

For example:

```js
const grid = $('#grid');
if (!grid) { return; }

const gridKendoGrid = grid.data('kendoGrid');
if (!gridKendoGrid) { return; }

const dataSource = gridKendoGrid.dataSource;
if (!dataSource) { return; }

dataSource.read().then(() => {
    const data = dataSource.data();
    if (!data) { return; }

    const failedIds = data
        .filter(row => row.status === 'N')
        .map(row => row.Id);
    console.log(failedIds);
});
```